# Ways to give 3 tickets to the cinema to 37 students: $P_{3,37}$ or $C_{3,37}$?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I think I have found a mistake in the task in the book and I am trying to figure out if that is true.

> There are thirty seven students in the class. Three tickets to the cinema will be given to three randomly chosen students. How many ways there are to give those tickets?

The answer in the book is $P_{3,37}=\frac{37!}{(37-3)!}$. This answer suggests that the order of picked students has meaning while in my opinion it doesn't have.

Shouldn't the answer be $C_{3,37}=\frac{37!}{3! \cdot (37-3)!}$?

Comment: It seems to me you are right since the tickets are indistinguishable.

Comment: You are probably right, but these might be tickets for different movies?

Comment: I agree that at best it's a poorly worded problem, but it is asking how many ways are there to "give" the tickets, which might imply that the order matters.

Comment: You're precisely right in that you identify the distinctness of the tickets as the deciding factor here; Perhaps the author's tickets are numbered.

Comment: Thank you all very much for answers. Probably there is some detail missing in the task as it is in the chapter regarding to permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, the solution hinges crucially on the distinguishability of the tickets.

If they are indistinguishable, the answer is $C_{3,37}$ as you proposed. If they're distinguishable, the answer is $P_{3,37}$ (for in this case, each permutation of the tickets must be counted separately).

Answer (score 1):

i think we must accept they are distinguishable because the tickets have different numbers (and so seats) from each other. So $\bf{permutation}$ is correct.